# Material Design Date picker date format

Tags: php, material-design

Im using material design date picker. I am currently trying to set the date format as follows:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    format:'yyyy/mm/dd'
});
```

The above is not working. May l please get the correct way of doing it.Thank you in advance

Comment: There is no problem with your code, you can check it out for yourself here https://jsfiddle.net/my2mnh9h/1/ - Open your browser's console and check if you have any other error.

Comment: Please specify "is not working". I see the folks answering here are already guessing what problems you are facing.

Comment: How is this related to `php`?

Answer (score 0):

get the date from the date picker and then process it like following

```
var date1 = new Date($('.datepicker').val());
date1 = date1.getFullYear() + '/' + (date1.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date1.getDate();
```